# Python library holidays with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I need to use a python library to find the list of US holidays for a given year, and I need this information for my ETL job to be deployed on AWS Glue service.

Panda is not supported currently by AWS Glue, and am wondering if there is any other library like holidays will work with AWS Glue?

According to glue documentation:

> You can use Python extension
>   modules and libraries with your AWS Glue ETL scripts as long as they
>   are written in pure Python. C libraries such as pandas are not
>   supported at the present time, nor are extensions written in other
>   languages.

Whats the possible way to calculate the US holidays for a given year?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted a working code that uses python library Holidays, instead of Pandas.  Sadly, Holidays is also not working in AWS Glue due to its limitations of Pure Python support - [python list of usa holidays between a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272664/python-list-of-usa-holidays-between-a-range)